# How do I change the origin for one mesh to be at the same point as another mesh

Tags: edit-mode

I have a project which consists of two 'parts', a hydraulic cylinders and their pistons. They are NOT joined. I have set the origin (marked with a red X in the image) for the cylinders to be where I want to pivot the entire assembly (cylinders and pistons) which works for the cylinders but not their pistons. I know that I could Join both together and the entire assembly would pivot but then I would not be able to move the cylinders (in and out of the cylinders) separately (marked with red double ended arrow).
What is the way I can achieve what I want to do? Is the only answer using an armature (don't know much about them).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could press `Shift S` and choose `Cursor to selected` given that the selected part is the one you want to copy the origin. Then select the object whose origin you want to change then go to `Object/Set Origin/ Origin to 3D cursor`.

Comment: Perfect.  Something else I have learned.  Thanks   That begs another question which perhaps I should start another question for maybe? Is it possible to extend the 'piston' in or out of the cylinder on the same 'plane' without having to rotate the whole assembly temporarily onto either the X or Y axis and then select the piston and use G X or G Y to extend the piston.?

Comment: Just select one of the faces that point to the direction you're looking for then set the `transform orientation` to this face. If you then move the cylinder along the Z axis, it will follow the direction of this plane.

Comment: Thanks again.  Just found a youtube video which explained just that seconds and then came back into the forum to advise and you answered seconds earlier. Thanks